# Can't modify django rest framework base.html file

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework, and as discribed here : [django rest framework doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api) I've added /rest_framework/api.html in my templates dir.

The structure now is :

```
|
|\
| apps
|  \
|   settings.py
\
 templates
  \
   rest_framework
    \
     api.html
```

api.html :

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}

{% block footer %}
    Hello !
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py :

...

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )),
)
```

...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.webdesign',
     ...
    'rest_framework',
     ...


)
```

...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}
```

The modification I do in api.html are not displayed in the browsable api. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Django REST Framework are you using?
I made changes to the block footer in the base.html and this was planed for the 3.0 release.

Is your 'Hello !' also not showing in the source code of the page (you can get it by pressing CTRL+U)?

If yes, than it could eventually be an issue with CSS making the colour white. You can put 'Hello !' in a tag like this: `<p>Hello !</p>`.

EDIT:

Additional info.

There was an issue with the sticky footer displaying always 60px below the page bottom, thus scrolling down was needed to see it. If you are using an older version this can be also causing the problem.
The most important question is: is 'Hello !' not at all in the source HTML sent to the browser or is it there, but you can't see it on the page?

Please give me a feedback, so we can solve this.

Answer (score 11):

Are you missing the DIRS from the main settings.py (this tells us where to look for templates (override templates):

```
 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ...
     }
```

Comment: somehow setting `'APP_DIRS': True'` doesn't properly scan you apps templates folders for `rest_framework/api.html`. Only way I could do it was explicitly creating a `templates/rest_framework/api.html` in my project root and then explicitly including it as suggested by this answer. Make sure you check your `BASE_DIR` value, since it depends on your settings organization (I have my `settings` in a child directory of my project root).

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier solution. Simply put `'rest_framework'` at the bottom of your `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Or at least after the app where you are overriding the api template. This way, django will go to your app's templates folder searching for `api.html` template before going to rest_framework tempalte folder.

Let's call this app 'myapi'. In my case I have:

**Project Structure**

```
project/
    myapi/
        templates/
            api/
                ...
            rest_framework/
                app.html
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'myapi',
    'rest_framework'
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

`djangorestframework==3.5.x`

I had the exact problem where the template was not picked up where the template existed in one of my project app directories, as such:

**`Project Structure`**

```
project/
    app1/
        templates/
            app1/
                ...
            rest_framework/
                app.html
```

**`settings.py`**

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG
        },
    },
]
```

I had to follow `joao figueiredo`'s comment, and add a specific template folder *outside* of the app directory.

**`Project Structure`**

```
project/
    app1/
        templates/
            app1/
                ...
    templates/  # Move your file to a specific template dir
        rest_framework/
            app.html
```

**`settings.py`**

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],  # look in this specific folder
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is crucial in Django >= 1.8 that you also add "APP_DIRS" to true in the TEMPLATES dictionary.

```
TEMPLATES = [ {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    ...  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may change your tempaltes settings to

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    ...
 }
```

if you use django1.8,that because it load tempalte diffrently,the BASE_DIR is for your templates,os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') is for django-rest-framework.

Comment: I faced this problem,the template load path some like .../tempaltes/templates/api.html so I added the BASE_DIR as tempaltes dirs that will make it find the temlate correctly,dont know why give me a down vote.