# Change default Django REST Framework home page title

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am following the [article](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) to set up a new Djangon REST framework project. I got it working but I would like to change the default home page title from `Django REST Framework v3.3.2 to` my own, I am sure it's just a setting somewhere but it didn't seem obvious which one, any insights will be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Based on the hints from @macro and this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991081/cant-modify-django-rest-framework-base-html-file), I got it to work with `api.html`. Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

After finding this answer - found it finally in the docs.
In case anyone is searching - I recommend checking out this [browsable api section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#customizing) in the docs.

From the docs:

> To customize the default style, create a template called
>   rest_framework/api.html that extends from rest_framework/base.html.

A sample file could be (templates/rest_framework/api.html):

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block branding %}
    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="nofollow" href="#">
        {% trans 'My new title' %}
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your templates directory make a folder called rest_framework inside that make a file called api.html and paste the following line in it `{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}`. Now to change the branding add

```
{% block branding %}
Your Branding
{% endblock %}
```

and for changing the title you add a title block and etc.

Answer (score 4):

From [the code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.3.2/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/base.html#L38), it looks like it's actually not a setting. You'll need to override the 'branding' block in the base template with your own content.

Basically you will need to make a copy of Django REST Framework's 'base.html' template file in your project's [template directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#dirs) with the same relative path, which will cause it to be loaded instead of DRF's template, and replace the content of that [block template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) with your branding.